# Consistent difference between network profile reputation and reputation in the site header

Tags: bug, reputation-graph, network-profile

My [StackExchange network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/460548/gert-arnold?tab=reputation) shows this:

[image].

The header of the Movies and TV site shows this:

[image]

This difference has persisted for well over 6 months. I reported it back in August 2012 (where the numbers were 833 and 941, respectively. Consensus at that time was that it was a caching issue. I think the duration of the difference shows that there really is a mismatch somewhere. For me the rep (either way) is not an important issue, but if this reveals a bug somewhere it's at least good to know it exists, I guess.

**Edit**

Two day after rep recalculation as suggested by JoachimSauer below: no difference (other sites' statistics are updated).

Comment: [Your profile over there](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/297/gert-arnold) shows 1061 for me.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, but the graph doesn't, even when the last rep event was days ago.

Comment: Ah, I see. Seems like it's "just" a bug with the graph (or maybe even just the labels). When I first read this, I thought you expected a much wider bug (like some general miscalculation happening).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I really don't know the scope of these calculations, just hope its not a big issue.

Comment: @GertArnold Most likely you broke it and you'll pay for it. You're on your own... :)

Comment: @Bart You may right be in so far that I've had a "history" at Movies. A massively upvoted question, including a rewarded bounty, was removed later when (beta) site policies changed, taking away part (not all - ??) of the rep. It was weeks after that that I first noticed the difference, so I can't really tell if this fact was related.

Comment: Have you tried triggering a rep recalc on the [Movies and TV Reputation page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/reputation)?

Comment: @JoachimSauer The depths of SE! Never knew this existed. Let me try.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Doesn't seem to make a difference. But maybe _that's_ a caching issue :).

Comment: Well, think I found the cause. In short: deleted posts. In detail, see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210958/152859

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Justice, finally! Good job. So you question should become an answer here I guess, if that belongs to the mod powers.

Comment: @GertArnold just giving evidence, justice will be made if and when this is actually fixed. :-)