# Network Profile reputation graph does not obey the sanity rules

Tags: bug, reputation-graph, network-profile

Take a look [at this](https://stackexchange.com/users/201110/shadow-wizard?tab=reputation): (no bragging just focus on the part in red circle)

> [image]

209 reputation on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), right? Well, [think again](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/106/shadow-wizard)!

> [image]

This is not the ordinary cache here, it's like that for long months now.

This made me curious, then furious and finally vicious so I went bug hunting. Here is my story.

Once upon a time, [a protocol for sanity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity) has been put on the table. One of its [immediate results](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/) was:

> if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should
> keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted.
> “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

Awesome! And indeed, on http://movies.stackexchange.com I had a question which had score of more than 3 and was visible for more than 60 days before getting deleted. The reputation I gained from it is preserved in all places... except my network profile reputation graph. :(

I thought to myself "209? Let's prove that's the reputation I have if using the old rules". So I had.

1. Start with 1 reputation point.
2. Association bonus of 100 → 101 points total
3. [One undeleted question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/227/106) with 11 upvotes and 2 downvotes → 110-4 = 106 net change → 207 points total
4. One approved [suggested edit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/4112) → 2 rep → 209 points total
   ##Q.E.D

Can the network profile reputation graph follow the same rules as the rest of the reputation calculations?

Comment: It's cachi... No wait.

Comment: I think I have an answer or two that's been deleted in a similar fashion which it seems to account for on MSO. Maybe it just hates Movies & TV. :P

Comment: @animuson can you merge this post as answer on the dupe then, since it 99.999% contains the cause?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I can't convert a question to an answer on another question. You're welcome to post this as an answer there and delete this, though.